# Alternative to css3 not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Are there any alternatives to the `:not` css3 selector that are compliant with IE8 (and quirks mode).

Either in css or javascript/jquery that emulates the selector or something similar.

I am using `*:not` as follows below. Feel free to recommend a solution that avoids the use of `:not` completely.

```
@media screen {
    #printable {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@media print {
    *:not(#printable) {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #printable {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Note that the use of `:not` is tied to the use of `@media print` so just using a simple jQuery solution to apply css to `$(":not(#printable)")` won't work without being clever.

Including an entire library like ie9.js or selectivirz isn't an option as it can effect various other parts of the pages and would involve a large section of re-testing.

a jsfiddle that shows it working in browsers that support `:not` http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/TjKbz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need `:not` in this case:

```
@media screen {
    #printable {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@media print {
    * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #printable {
        position: absolute;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

The selector `#printable` has a higher priority than `*` so your `#printable` element will be visible.

Comment: bear in mind that sub elements of #printable will be hidden unless you also style `#printable *` as visible. So @hardyharzen's answer is better. Also `hidden` elements still show up as blank space; you may want to use `display:none;` instead.

Comment: @Spudley `display none;` used on the container of #printable will remove #printable

Answer (score 1):

You could try specificity overrides, i.e.

```
@media print {
  * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printable, #printable * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

See [Add CSS3 support to IE7+ with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131485/add-css3-support-to-ie7-with-javascript) and http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: I specifically mentioned using those libraries isn't an option.