# nth-child() is not working in ie8 /7

Tags: css

```
ul li:nth-child(odd){
color:#c0122f;

float:left;

width:48%; 

line-height:30px; 

font-size:15px;
}




ul li:nth-child(even){
color:#c0122f;

width:48%;

float:right; 

line-height:30px;

font-size:15px;
}
```

there is six li item on my page and i want give 3 shold be left side and 3 should be right side for that i have used nth-child(odd)/ even which i show in my code its working fine in chrome, mozilla and ie9 but it create a problem in ie8 /7

Comment: ie7/8 do not support nth-child(): http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Check it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Browser_compatibility) too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add CSS3 support to IE7+ with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131485/add-css3-support-to-ie7-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

They don't support `nth-child`. You'll need to implement a javascript solution for those browsers, unfortunately.

Comment: the link which u provide its not make any sens don't take in awrong way it not helpfull for me i am still stuck with my problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry `nth-child` aren't supported in those versions of IE. It included support for these properties later! Not in those versions.

However, here is an alternate way!

Use this script: http://selectivizr.com/ it would enable some CSS properties.

**Note:** You should always try to search for browser compatibility and some script which would help you use CSS in older versions of IE!

Comment: "You should always try to search for browser compatibility and some script which would help you use CSS in older versions of IE!" -- Wrong, you should always consider your demographic and code to the majority of users. If the user base is mostly IE6, loading up the page with a bunch of javascript is going to kill UX and thus, your bottom end. Always ALWAYS engineer, never hack.

Comment: Hehehe even Microsoft prevents users from using IE6 now! :) So, you can just tell the users with IE6 to update their browser, I just said to search, I didn't say to just search and never use JS..I did mention JS!

Comment: Yes, they do. But that doesn't mean that ENTERPRISES around the world are listening. Again, engineering means you find the right solution to the problem. Hacking is slapping a bunch of scripts at a problem without knowing the final impact. He is clearly targeting older browsers for a reason.

Comment: Yes, and so if he has a reason then he should find the solution! :)

Comment: Agreed. And he is doing so by posting on SO. However, you've suggested lighting a cigarette with a cruise missile and present it like its the only way. There are MANY MANY other alternatives to scripts like graceful degradation or progressive enhancement.

Comment: Guys tell me the exact solution how can i use nth-child in ie8

Comment: @user3124228 Take a look at feme97's post. Thats a nice way to ensure a consistent user experience for all without loading another lib for a singular need.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mentioned, nth child is not supported in older versions of IE. You could add fallback classes to IE versions if you add IE conditionals to your html tag. Then just do some basic jQuery to add classes.

**html**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

**jquery**

```
$('.lt-ie9 li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
$('.lt-ie9 li:nth-child(even)').addClass('even');
```

**css**

```
li.odd,
li:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #c0122f;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell how can i implement in css code i am getting confused kindly give the exact code

Comment: Not sure what other examples I can give. The js will add a class of 'odd' or 'even' to those li elements, so you would just add the `li.odd` or `li.even` to your existing css for those.